# Why use interface and abstract over just abstract?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class, derived-class

I'm reading some code online where someone implemented the following classes: `IMapObj` which is a normal interface, `AbstractMapObj` that derives from that interface and a lot of map objects that derive from `AbstrsctMapObj`.

Throughout all his code, he refers to `IMapObj` and not `AbstractMapObj`.

What's the benefit of using an interface **and** an abstract class instead of just an abstract class? Needless to say no other class derives from `IMapObj`, only `AbstractMapObj`.

Comment: Because there is no multiple inheritance?

Comment: Because they serve different purposes?

Comment: @UweKeim The code doesn't include multiple inheritance anyway. Also, the properties that are included inside `IMapObj` can be put into `AbstractMapObj` as it's the only place they're used.

Comment: Because abstract classes can also contain funcitons with code and you can provide a basic Interfaceimplementation for all the things that derive AbstractMapObj ?

Comment: It sounds like there may be _no point_ in this particular case.

Comment: _"... that derives from that interface"_  first wrong turn. It _implements_ the interface. But I second Jamie: In the structure described, it's somewhat superfluent.

Comment: Likely this is before you could put implementation into an interface which is why there's an abstract class (to include common implementation).  As for why there's an interface that's because an interface defines an exact API and allows for decoupling vs having stuff rely on the abstract class.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams Did any of the answers below answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

There is only 1 reason to use both, and that is that the abstract class can provide a default implementation of *some* or *all* of the functionality. The interface can be easily mocked for testing.

Comment: Weeeelll, I could also imagine two (or n) completely disjunct inheritance trees implementing the same interface ... _theoretically_

Comment: *disjoint ^^ not "disjunct" (sorry, english is my 2nd language)

Answer (score 3):

> What's the benefit of using an interface and an abstract class instead of just an abstract class?

In the example posted, there appears to be no real reason to use an abstract class.  In other scenarios, the abstract class could provide a common base to a **subset** of the interface implementations.  With the interface providing a more stable/common abstraction for the rest of the application/library.

---

Generally *I* would only use an abstract class to share a common implementation, not as an interface definition - but that's just my preference.  There are many different styles and patterns that people use.